# Fifo Method using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, fifo

I need one adaptation for the first table because there are negative issues  points and I need the net table considerating the negatives points as debit of the first time of issue. E.g:

```
Date of issue   Number of account   Issued points
30-abr                    1            300
31-may                    1             50
30-jun                    1            100
30-jun                    1            -50
30-abr                    2            200
31-may                    2             60
```

I want this table

```
Date of issue   Number of account   Issued points
30-abr                    1            250
31-may                    1             50
30-jun                    1            100
30-abr                    2            200
31-may                    2             60
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: i think he's asking us to write a query for him/her.

Comment: Yes, I need if you can help me with the code in SQL.

Comment: We can assist you with what you have, but we will not do it for you without seeing what effort you put in.  In other words, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi! I have this code. The problem is that doesn't do anything with the points that were debited in a date that there are not issues point. How can you recommend me change that query? Thanks!

with cte as(
select Fechaemi, Cuenta,PtosEmi,PtosCan,row_number() over (partition by Fechaemi,Cuenta order by Fechaemi,Cuenta) as rank
from emision)
select a.Fechaemi, a.Cuenta,a.PtosEmi - coalesce(b.PtosCan, 0) stock
from cte a
 left join cte b on a.FechaEmi= b.FechaEmi and a.Cuenta = b.Cuenta and a.rank = b.rank - 1
where a.PtosEmi - coalesce(b.PtosCan, 0) > 0
order by a.cuenta asc, a.fechaemi asc